# How to encode ttsJson data?

Tags: json

I am having problem when i want to encode data like ttsjson or is there any way that can get the data to encode it?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pfM9K.png)

Please tell me what I need to do.
I tried decoding but the code often crashes. Is there any way to read how the web encodes?